# What is a subsystem (for example, the netfilter subsystem)?

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel

My question is not about netfilter. What I want to know is what the term "Subsystem" means.

I am studying for RHCSA and my workbook defines netfilter as a subsystem. We generally talk about utilities, programs, services or daemons.

What exactly is a subsystem? What are its components? How is it configured? How is it different from a daemon or a service?

Comment: *daemon* or *service* refer to userspace processes.  [netfilter](https://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-hacking-HOWTO-3.html) is part of the kernel networking stack.

Answer (score 2):

*Subsystem* has no special meaning in the Linux world.

I think the definition in your workbook is confusing.  You can forget that definition, and just keep in mind that `netfilter` is part of the kernel networking stack (as said by @user4556274) and is a *framework* that provides firewalling capabilities in Linux.

Comment: Can you please explain the term framework? I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: From Wikipedia: *A software framework is an abstraction in which software providing generic functionality can be selectively changed by additional user-written code, thus providing application-specific software. A software framework is a universal, reusable software environment that provides particular functionality as part of a larger software platform to facilitate development of software applications, products and solutions.* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework

Comment: Your answer is very misleading - the Linux kernel has very definite subsystems. Each subsystem has a dedicated maintainer, to find them check the MAINTAINERS file in any Linux kernel tree (such as https://www.kernel.org/doc/linux/MAINTAINERS).

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, the term subsystem is used to describe part of the kernel internal architecture. The MAINTAINERS file in any Linux kernel code tree lists the subsystems, and, for example, https://www.kernel.org/doc/linux/MAINTAINERS has 'SUBSYSTEM' appearing 64 times.

In the case of netfilter, this is a subsystem of the kernel, and it's functionality is provided by a discrete part of the kernel, and has it's own well defined API. (Although the kernel MAINTAINERS file has a maintainer listed for it, it's not described explicitly as a subsystem).

Generally, in system engineering a system can be split into several distinct parts but this split is often arbitrary, albeit logical, and there are no hard rules on how to do it.

As a brief overview of the Linux kernel subsystems in particular, this article may be useful - [Anatomy of the Linux kernel](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-linux-kernel/%20Anatomy%20of%20the%20Linux%20kernel%20-%20IBM)